# Jquery resizeable auto resize parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I've got a couple of nested resizable div's that need to resize to accommodation the child size.
Everything works fine until i try to resize one of the outer div's (vertically) then it gets stuck.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MuGjc/).

```
$(function () {
$('.block').resizable();
$('.block').resize(resize_handler);
});

function checkChildren(object) {
$(object).children(".block").each(function (index, item) {
    var itemH = $(item).position().top + $(item).height();
    var itemW = $(item).position().left + $(item).width();

    if ($(object).width() < itemW) {
        $(item).width($(object).width());
        checkChildren($(item));
    }
    if ($(object).height() < itemH) {
        $(item).height($(object).height());
        checkChildren($(item));
    }
});
}

function checkParent(e) {

var object = $(e);
var par = object.parent();

var totalW = object.width() + object.position().left;
var totalH = object.height() + object.position().top;

if (totalH > par.height()) {
    par.height(totalH);
    checkParent(par);
}

if (totalW > par.width()) {
    par.width(totalW);
    checkParent(par);
}
}

function resize_handler(e, ui) {
e.stopPropagation();

var object = $(this);
var par = object.parent();

if (par.hasClass("block")) {
    checkParent(object);
}
if (object.children('.block').length > 0) {
    checkChildren(object);
}

}
```

Comment: Can you define the problem more specifically? What do you mean by "stuck"?

Comment: what i mean when is when one of the outer vertical boards hits a child board it continues to resize it [link]http://jsfiddle.net/MuGjc/

Answer (score 0):

Sure you've already thought of this but could you try limiting the resizeability of the parent div if its height is too close to the height of its child. Meaning when it is about to come in contact with the edge of a child then don't allow it to come any closer. Maybe maintain a buffer around the children of a few pixels which would force the user to adjust the child first before they could adjust the parent any smaller.

Just a thought.